# json encode and php array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to get the following output that will produce the following json

```
[{"description":"name","errorcode":777},{"description":"Department","errorcode":"yyy"}]
```

PHP

```
if(empty($name)){        
    $errordesc[] = array('description' => 'name','errorcode' =>  777);           
}
else if(empty($email)){
    $errordesc[] = array('description' => 'Department','errorcode' =>  "yyy");
}
```

when I do

```
 echo json_encode($errordesc);
```

it gives output as

```
[{"description":"name","errorcode":-2}]
```

The problem is in the php array.Should I use array_push?
Please advice.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$array[] = x` is the same as `array_push($array, x)`.

Comment: Where is `-2` coming from? Maybe there's some other code that's overwriting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code currently has the following structure:

```
if (condition) {
    # code...
} 
elseif (condition) {
    # code...
}
```

The code inside this block will get executed **only** if the first `if` condition evaluates to `FALSE`. The JSON output you're getting suggests that only one of the conditional blocks is being considered.

If you want to do both the checks, try using the following structure:

```
if (condition) {
    # code...
} 
if (condition) {
    # code...
}
```

---

With your code, it should look like:

```
if(empty($name)){        
    $errordesc[] = array('description' => 'name','errorcode' =>  777);           
}
if(empty($email)) {
    $errordesc[] = array('description' => 'Department','errorcode' =>  "yyy");
}
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/52610)

Comment: Thanks Amal. The problem was in the if else as you stated.

Answer (score 3):

The is a syntax error in your code

```
else if(empty($email){<-----here

else if(empty($email)){<-----must be like this
```

Seeing your code actually i think the array contains only one item ,that is why you get that out put array push is not required just correct your logic.

```
 $errordesc[] = array('description' => 'name1','errorcode' =>  1); 
 $errordesc[] = array('description' => 'name2','errorcode' =>  2); 

echo json_encode($errordesc);
```

you will get json string with two items

```
[{"description":"name1","errorcode":1},{"description":"name2","errorcode":2}]
```

Comment: That is almost certainly just a copying error, since the code with a missing `)` wouldn't even run.

Comment: hmm...I have corrected the missing bracket but still getting only one item...strange.

Answer (score 1):

Using `else` means you'll just get one or the other entry in your array. If you want them both, try:

```
if(empty($name)){        
    $errordesc[] = array('description' => 'name','errorcode' =>  777);           
}
if(empty($email){
    $errordesc[] = array('description' => 'Department','errorcode' =>  "yyy");
}
```

I'm not sure why the error for a missing email says `Department` rather than `email`, but that's a different problem.

Comment: I think he's made lots of SO copying mistakes -- there's no `-2` in the code, yet it's in the output.

Comment: ya i either he has not shown the full code or he is assuming the output

Comment: Thanks barmar.The problem was in the if else :)